# libtcod game build with py2app "Library not loaded: @loader_path/.dylibs/SDL2"

Tags: python, importerror, sdl-2, dylib, py2app

I build a little roguelike game with https://github.com/libtcod/python-tcod and
it's working fine when I run the "main.py" file using my Python interpreter.

So, I wanted to share my little creation with other people. The problem is that when I try to create the app using py2app (https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) the application crashes when starting.

This is the full traceback of the error:

```
roguelike git:(build-mac) ./dist/main.app/Contents/MacOS/main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/roguelike/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 101, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/roguelike/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 84, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/roguelike/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tcod
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "tcod/__init__.pyc", line 18, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "tcod/loader.pyc", line 111, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "tcod/_libtcod.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "tcod/_libtcod.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/username/PycharmProjects/roguelike/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/tcod/_libtcod.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/.dylibs/SDL2
  Referenced from: /Users/username/PycharmProjects/roguelike/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/tcod/_libtcod.so
  Reason: image not found
2020-11-29 18:04:37.832 main[21123:2360673] main Error
```

I think the problem is here:

> Library not loaded: @loader_path/.dylibs/SDL2

But I'm not sure how to check to what path "@loader_path" resolves to, nor how to fix it so my "app" can be run in any Mac. Ideally I would like my app to use the SDL2 that is packed in main.app/Contents/Frameworks/SDL2

Comment: From `man dyld`: "This variable is replaced with the path to the directory containing the mach-o binary which contains the load command using `@loader_path`. Thus, in every binary, `@loader_path` resolves to a different path, [...]." It seems that in your case, this would be `/Users/username/PycharmProjects/roguelike/dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/tcod`. You might also want to check out `man install_name_tool`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Now it's working, after moving SDL2 from Frameworks to the loader path
`cp dist/main.app/Contents/Frameworks/SDL2 dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/tcod/.dylibs`
But I still don't understand why is this needed.